# How to Name a Java Repository class which deals with multiple repos

Tags: java-8, naming-conventions, dao

Consider I have three repository classes which are `StudentRepository.java`, `SubjectRepository.java` and `ActivityRepository.java`.

`StudentRepository.java` - deals interaction with the database for `Student` class
`SubjectRepository.java` - deals interaction with the database for `Subject` class
`ActivityRepository.java` - deals interaction with the database for `Activity` class

Assume that I'm going to provide a report about the subject activities for students. So I'm to join all the three classes (related tables). What do I name the class which deals with all three tables?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know about code review - stack exchange @RavindraRanwala

Comment: @user10974034 If you ask this on Code Review, please read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) and include the code you want reviewed in the post. Otherwise you'll get downvoted and your question closed in seconds.

Comment: After reading code review [help center], it seems my question did not suit their terms. My question is just a suggestion. Can you help this out?? @Peilonrayz

Comment: @user10974034 Thank you for reading over the help center first! Yes it does seem like your question couldn't possibly be on-topic there as you seem to be asking what to name your fourth class. Unfortunately I'm unsure if this would be on-topic anywhere. Personally, given the information, I would call it something like `StudentManager`. However I would suggest you think about what this new class will achieve, is it something like a GradeRepository or a SemesterRepository? Unfortunately I don't have the information to say what is best. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It really helped a bit. @Peilonrayz